# In android how can I save an RTSP stream to file while playing it?

Tags: android, media-player, rtsp

I need to be able to play a video received over RTSP AND save it to disc (well, the SD card) at the same time. This is a live stream, so I cannot download the entire file first and then play it. I must play and record simultaneously. I can record video from the on board camera using MediaRecorder, and I can receive an RTSP stream using MediaPlayer or VideoView, but I don't know how to combine the two.

MediaRecorder seems to be the only way to record video, but it only supports one video source: the camera. Its setVideoSource() method allows no other sources. Perhaps I need to get an OutputStream somehow, which I can then write to a file?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Mark did you manage to solve this somehow?

Comment: this link may help.. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/

Comment: library https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Comment: @Mark did u find any solution??

Comment: No, I did not. Sorry!

Comment: Did ANYBODY find a solution in the last _5 years_?

Comment: Take a look at our solution using `ffmpeg` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679879/293280

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is hard.
There is no easy way to do this.

You have to get the video stream inside the RTSP packet by yourself (good luck with that, there is no free library to do it, it took me hours and hours of work) and store the stream in a file, in the same time, your can read this file and play it, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747060/how-do-you-play-android-inputstream-on-mediaplayer).

Comment: can you explain how to do first step please, have you a sample?

Comment: Can you please post the link how you did it?

Comment: Any idea if things have improved in the last 7 years?