# Wifi Direct - streaming video from one device to other

Tags: android, video-streaming, wifi-direct

Please help me getting started
how do i achieve live streaming of video on one device on another using Wifi Direct.
I have already established connection between the two devices.What is the next step to follow

Comment: do you have any demo code to show what you have achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [WIFI-Direct documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

First you need to establish a connection. there is enough code in the documentation to do that.

Then, then you send the file as a stream and receive it on the other side. Now, based on [Android MediaPlayer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) you need to send the received stream to the mediaplayer. There are different ways to approach this like saving the stream to a file and then passing the file to the mediaplayer. But a better way is implementing a localhttpserver and passing the local uri to the mediaplayer.

I gathered this info from the links below:

[Write to file and stream from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747060/how-do-you-play-android-inputstream-on-mediaplayer)

[Modifying FileInputStream for mediaPlayer setDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257364/modifying-fileinputstream-for-mediaplayer-setdatasource)

[Android ServerSocket programming with jCIFS streaming files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058135/android-serversocket-programming-with-jcifs-streaming-files)

[Create mediaplayer with inputstream in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272664/create-mediaplayer-with-inputstream-in-android)

[Sample Local HTTP server](https://gist.github.com/abeluck/6243306)

Comment: On other side, Can we send music stream direct to music player than storing it into external/internal sdcard?

Comment: well, I believe implementing a localhttpserver will get you the same as you're asking. basically you're providing a stream to the other side instead of sending the whole file and saving it... However I am not sure what you mean by music player, if you meant any music player, my answer is I don't know.

Comment: If I am streaming high definition video, what is the number of nodes that a Group Owner support to have a realistic and good stream ? ie, what are the capabilities of a non entry level device in respect to number of other devices (slaves) it can support?