# Save a RTSP stream to mp4 file in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am working on a project where I need to read input stream from an IPCamera. I am able to fetch this in through an rtsp url.

Display the IPCamera stream. I am able to do same by using -

```
    videoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://xxxxxxxx/camera1"));
    videoView.requestFocus();
```

Now I want to record this stream to an MP4 file. For same I am using mediarecorder.Here I am stuck.

```
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    //mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("rtsp://xxxxxxxxx/camera1");
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaRecorder.start();
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you got a solution for this?

Comment: @somia I just posted our solution for it, using `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `ffmpeg`.

1. Add `ffmpeg` dependency.

   ```
   compile 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5'
   ```
2. Record Stream.

   ```
   String RTSP_URL = "rtsp://<your_rtsp_url>";

   final File targetFile = new File( getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES )  + "/recording1.mp4" );

   final FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);

   String[] ffmpegCommand = new String[]{  "-i", RTSP_URL, "-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec", "copy", targetFile.toString() };

   final FFtask ffTask = ffmpeg.execute( ffmpegCommand, new FFcommandExecuteResponseHandler() {

     @Override
     public void onStart() {}

     @Override
     public void onProgress(String message) {}

     @Override
     public void onFailure(String message) {}

     @Override
     public void onSuccess(String message) {}

     @Override
     public void onFinish() {}

   } );

   final Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

   TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() { @Override public void run() {
     ffTask.sendQuitSignal();
   } };

   timer.schedule( timerTask, 30000 ); // Will stop recording after 30 seconds.
   ```