# OpenCV Android Studio Java IP Camera Not Connecting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

I am currently trying to develop an app using android studio that connects two **IP cameras** and streams them concurrently.

I am currently having issues connecting my IP cameras using `OpenCV video capture` using the following url which was confirmed to be correct by the manufacturer

`rtsp://(myUsername):(myPassword)@192.168.0.34:554/stream1`

This url also works with VLC player but when I run the application I get no connection or error message checking that the connection is open with `capture.isOpened().`

The camera I'm using is a `tp-link tapo 100`
if anyone has any suggestions that would be great, thanks.

```
videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
videoCapture.open("rtsp://(myUsername):(myPassword)@192.168.0.34:554/stream1");

if (!videoCapture.isOpened()) {
  System.out.println("ERROR CONNECTING TO CAMERA");
} else {
  System.out.println("video is captured!");
}
```

Comment: *"I run the application I get no connection or error message checking that the connection is open with capture.isOpened()"* So if there is no error, where is the actual problem?

Comment: there is no connection to the camera being made...

Answer (score 1):

please post the error log you getting from logcat
open cv doesn't handle `rtsp` links like the usual `http` links you will need to use frames instead and then convert those frames into a video

Comment: What do you mean by saying " *you will need to use frames instead and then convert those frames into a video* "

Comment: like i said there is no error message, just black screen. i am unfamiliar with logcat so can't get the log for you. i also tried androids native rtsp support using video view which also didn't work so i am running out of ideas

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I meant like using a library to convert frames to videos since opencv can pick frames ffrom an rtsp link but not videos

Comment: @EnterNameHere Logcat is a panel in android studio that shows you the current events occuring while you are running the app whilst being connected to the pc I would suggest you add a library called ffmpeg and do [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679879/8872691) this example you convert the stream into video then play the video immediately which will simulate a live stream

Comment: tried the ffmpeg solution and got the error no such file or directory using the same url as the one that works with the vlc desktop player..

Answer (score 0):

Try using MediaPlayer you will just need to configure your XML and add for the additional camera.

**Code**

public class
MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

```
final static String USERNAME = "admin";
final static String PASSWORD = "camera";
final static String RTSP_URL = "Your URL Goes Hear";
private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set up a full-screen black window.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.black);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Configure the view that renders live video.
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    _surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    _surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    _surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(1024, 600);
}

/*SurfaceHolder.Callback*/
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sh, int f, int w, int h) {}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sh)
{
    _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    _mediaPlayer.setDisplay(_surfaceHolder);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Map<String, String> headers = getRtspHeaders();
    Uri source = Uri.parse(RTSP_URL);
    try
    {
        // Specify the IP camera's URL and auth headers.
        _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, headers);

        // Begin the process of setting up a video stream.
        _mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        _mediaPlayer.prepare();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder sh)
{
    _mediaPlayer.release();
}
private Map<String, String> getRtspHeaders()
{
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String basicAuthValue = getBasicAuthValue(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    headers.put("Authorization", basicAuthValue);
    return headers;
}
private String getBasicAuthValue(String usr, String pwd)
{
    String credentials = usr + ":" + pwd;
    int flags = Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP;
    byte[] bytes = credentials.getBytes();
    return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(bytes, flags);
}

/*MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener*/
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
{
    _mediaPlayer.start();
}
```