# Exoplayer Android. How to record the streamed RTSP video

Tags: android, rtsp, exoplayer

I am successful in streaming the RTSP live video via hikvision IPCamera to my android app. Now I want to record the streaming video in the mobile app itself. How would I do it? Can I have some guidance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416052/save-a-rtsp-stream-to-mp4-file-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself. I was successful in streaming the rtsp feed in my app using [pedroSG94/vlc-example-streamplayer](https://github.com/pedroSG94/vlc-example-streamplayer) . But I was unable to record the stream in my android app. After a week of trial and failure using different techniques, I finally found the actual [vlc-android](https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android) compiled sdk posted by vlc themself. This library had both the streaming and recording feature which helped me accomplish my goal. Thank you `vlc`

Comment: So you found a way to record and display at the same time? Could you show us how?

Comment: Ah, by using duplicate: `media.addOption(":sout=#duplicate{dst=file{dst=\"" + filesDir.absolutePath + "/test_stream.mp4\"}, dst=display}")`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the actual [vlc-android](https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android) compiled sdk posted by vlc themself.

VLC library for android implementation.

('org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.3.14')

Use this library for streaming and recording RTSP video